# Electric dipole field from gradient of dipole potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

I'm going through the Griffiths E&M book and I'm trying to figure out how to get the electric field from a perfect dipole by taking the gradient of the potential $$V_{dip}(\textbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{\textbf{p}\cdot\hat{\textbf{r}}}{r^2}\right]$$
However, I always seem to end up part way with 
$$\nabla V_{dip}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{1}{r^2}\nabla(\textbf{p}\cdot\hat{\textbf{r}})+(\textbf{p}\cdot\hat{\textbf{r}})\cdot\frac{-2\hat{\textbf{r}}}{r^3}\right]$$
which has some elements of the correct answer (mostly the $(\textbf{p}\cdot\hat{\textbf{r}})\cdot\frac{\hat{\textbf{r}}}{r^3}$ part), but I'm a bit stuck on how to continue.  Expanding out the gradient leaves me with a curl of **p** term, which can be non-zero, and so I can't figure out how to progress through that.  I'm also not sure what to do with the -2 factor, as in the answer I would be expecting a factor of -3 at this stage.  I'm trying to find a solution that only uses vector identities, so not making any assumptions such as **p** is in the z direction.  Any help would go a long way thanks!

Comment: I have removed the comments that were providing hints rather that seeking to clarify or improve the question. Comments are transient and subject to deletion at any time. If there is an answer for the question, it should be posted as an answer. Please reserve comments for clarifying the question or suggesting improvements to the question. Thanks!